# Duplicated variables in an array when not meant to be duplicated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this very small piece of code

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
    var ball = balls[i];
    totalBalls.push( ball );
}
```

When i try this

```
console.log( totalBalls[0].xPos ) // = 10
console.log( totalBalls[1].xPos ) // = 10
balls.xPos += 10;
console.log( totalBalls[0].xPos ) // 20
console.log( totalBalls[1].xPos ) // 20
```

Why is the second element in the array the same as the first element in the array?

Comment: _Objects_ are references

Comment: Without seeing how the "balls" array is initialized, it'll be hard to give a precise answer.

Comment: so basically I need to create a new ball for each ball that is used in the for loop?

Comment: From what you've posted here, I would assume that `balls[0]` and `balls[1]` from the original array are the same object.

Comment: @Canvas There's too much information missing. Show how `balls` is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the second element in the array the same as the first element in the array?

*Objects* are kept as references, i.e.

```
a = {foo: 'bar'};
a.foo; // "bar"
b = a;
b.foo = null;
a.foo; // null
```

So when you do `push`, it doesn't create a new *Object* which is a clone of `ball`, but rather creates a new reference to the place in memory where `ball` already is.